# listview of lists in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I wanna make a list of lists in my activity. Lets say a list of months and when I choose one of the months, I will get a new list with data entries for that month.

I've added some pic to help understand.

Can you guys tell me\point me to how it can be done? (P.S, I am looking for the answer in other similar questions)

[image]

Comment: you want the list to be "recreated" with the new selected list or you just want to "load" the selected list in the same viewport?

Comment: I want the list to be recreated. Not to be in the same list under the selected header if that what you meant

Comment: Is this data coming from a database?

Comment: If you don't have to display old listview. Simple create new adapter and add to your listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, the best solution is that on each list item click you should create a new `Adapter` according to the selection and then set it on the `ListView` itself.

If you want to have navigation inside the items then you might probably want to create some tree structure through code in order to determine which list is the previous one.

If you need some sample code, let me know.

Although you should probably check `ExpandableListView` as one of the possible alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list activity containing the list of months, and using

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
```

you can use intents to another listactivity for different view selected. 
I have created an example project in of my posts on my blog ([Android List View](http://collegewires.com/android/2012/06/android-list-view/))

Comment: wouldn't I need to create 12 classes of listActivity for the 12 months then?